# Who was Barbarika?

Tags: mahabharata, skanda-purana

I think Barbarika was son of arjun and came from patal lok of ancient time, Lord Khatu-Shayam is the same Warrior who was killed by Lord Krishna.

Who trained Barbarika to become so powerful, in a book I read most of the warriors were also scientists, So basically he invented this "self-propelled precision-guided munition system" which was able to attack anything by his guildelines.

What is the truth?

I have read a book *अतीत का दिग्दर्शन (atīt kā digdarśan)*, which says Barbarika was son of "Arjuna and king of PatalPuri"

This is the Book

[image]

(Brabhuvahan was Barbarika introduced himself to Krishna)
[image]

(Barbarika said I don't have army, Krishna wanted to test him)
[image]

(Barbarika was able to finish every thing with in a moment)
[image]

Comment: BTW where did u read about that country being the Patala Loka ? Which book ?  I too read that its being the Atala Loka..But these atala, vitala, sutala, patala etc  are the Adholokas (nether worlds) and our earth is the Bhu Loka..Then how come in ancient times these Adholokas  were on earth ?

Comment: @Rickross It is said that height from sea level was very low (Of USA in that time) comparing to our country, Regarding the book I will update the information soon. Thanks

Comment: He was a warrior. In mahabharata. He was about to fight from the side of kaurava.but lord Krishna took his test and gave him mufkti.. he was the one who saw mahabharta on top of mountain from his only beheaded head

Comment: @Rishi Rishi, the book? You've updated it yet.very eagerly waiting for your reference.

Comment: @user129402 I am going to home town tomorrow on weekend, I will add the screen shots, thanks for waiting. Also in that book Barbarika is son of Arjuna.

Comment: @Rishi  did you? The book, oh thou great Rishi? ;)

Comment: @user129402 i hope you know hindi, see question

Comment: @Rishi Nope I don't know Hindi :/ but yeh! English translation of it as you added I could see,  "Aditi ka digdharsan'. Got it. sad that I couldn't read that book since it's in Hindi :(

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Story of Barbarika is mentioned in detail in **Kaumarika Khanda, Maheswara Khanda of Skanda Mahapurana.**

Barbarika was son of Ghatotkacha and Kāmakaṭankaṭa. Gatotkacha was son of Hidambi and Pandava Bhima.

In city of [Pragjyotisapura](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kamakhya_Temple), there was Rakshasa Muru who was defence officer of Asura Naraka. Sri Krishna [killed](http://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/10/59/2-3) Narakasura and Mura. Muru's daughter, kāmakaṭankaṭa , fought with Sri Krishna as He killed her father. But kāmakaṭankaṭa  was devotee of Goddess Kamakhya and Goddess Kamakhya suggested not to fight with Sri Krishna. Thereafter, she married Ghatotkacha.

Complete story of events that lead to their marriage are described in **[Chapter 59](http://www.hinduscriptures.in/scriptures/puranas-18-puranas-mahapurana/skanda-purana/vol-ii/chapter-59/topic-1) and Chapter 60 of Kaumarika Khanda.**

Birth of Barbarika is mentioned in **[Chapter 60](http://www.hinduscriptures.in/scriptures/puranas-18-puranas-mahapurana/skanda-purana/vol-ii/chapter-60/topic-2) of Kaumarika Khanda.**

> ततो वनेषु चित्रेषु निम्नगापुलिनेषु च । 
>  रेमे सह तया
> भैमिर्मन्दोदर्येव रावणः ॥ ६०-६१
>
> 61.Thereafter, the son of Bhima sported with her in the forests of variegated colours and the banks of rivers like Ravana along with
> Mandodari.
>
> एवं विक्रीडितस्तस्य गर्भो जज्ञे महाद्युतेः । 
> हैडिम्भैराक्षसव्याघ्राद्बालसूर्यसमप्रभः ॥ ६०-६२
>
> 62.Even as the son of Hidambi, a tiger among Raksasas, (a leader) of great lustre was sporting about thus, a son was born to him. He had
> the lustre of the rising sun.
>
> स जातमात्रो ववृधे क्षणाद्यौवनगोऽभवत् । 
>  नीलमेघचयप्रख्यो घटास्यो
> दीर्घलोचनः ॥ ६०-६३
>
> ऊर्ध्वकेशश्चोर्ध्वरोमा पितरौप्रणतोऽब्रवीत् । 
>  प्रणमामि
> युवांचोभौजातस्यपितरौगुरू ॥ ६०-६४
>
> भवतोर्हिप्रियंकृत्वाअनृणःस्यांसदाह्यहम् । 
> भवद्भ्यांदत्तमिच्छामिअभिधानंयथात्मनः ॥ ६०-६५
>
> अतः परंतु यच्छ्रेयः कर्तव्यंप्रोन्नतिप्रदम् । 
>  ततो
> भैमिस्तमालिङ्ग्य पुत्रं वचनमब्रवीत् ॥ ६०-६६
>
> 63-66. **As soon as he was born, he increased in size. In a moment he
> became a young man. He had the lustre of a blue cloud. His face
> resembled a pot. He had long eyes. His hair on the head as well as on
> the body rose up.** He bowed down to his parents and said: “I bow down
> to both of you. Parents are the preceptors of a person born. I shall
> become free from the indebtedness to you by always doing what is
> pleasing to you. I wish to have a name given by you two. Thereafter
> what is conducive to welfare and prosperity should be performed.'
>
> Thereupon the son of Bhima embraced his son and spoke these words:
>
> बर्बराकारकेशत्वाद्बर्बरीकाभिधोभवान् । 
>  भविष्यति महाबाहो
> कुलस्याऽऽनन्दवर्धनः ॥ ६०-६७
>
> श्रेयश्च ते यत्परमं दृढं च तत्कीर्त्यते बहुधा विप्रमुख्यैः । 
> प्रक्ष्यावहे तद्यदुवंशनाथं गत्वा पुरीं द्वारकां वासुदेवम् ॥ ६०-६८
>
> 67-68. “**Since you have the hair like that of a Barbara, you will be
> named Barbarika,** O mighty-armed one, You will increase the delight
> of the family. What is conducive to your welfare is glorified by the
> leading Brahmanas in various ways. Therefore, we shall go to the city
> of Dvaraka and ask Vasudeva, the Lord of the race of Yadu.'

Sri Krishna blessed the boy and taught him Kshatriya Dharma. As per suggestions of Krishna, Barbarika pleased various forms of Mother Goddess. Barbarika helped Brahmana Vijaya in performing Ganeswara Homa and **Devas granted him the sacred ash obtained in Homam**, which is mentioned in detail in **[Chapter 61](http://www.hinduscriptures.in/scriptures/puranas-18-puranas-mahapurana/skanda-purana/vol-ii/chapter-61/topic1) and [Chapter 63](http://www.hinduscriptures.in/scriptures/puranas-18-puranas-mahapurana/skanda-purana/vol-ii/chapter-63/topic-1).**

Thereafter, Barbarika met Bhima and other Pandavas at Mahi Sagara Sangama, as described in **[Chapter 64](http://www.hinduscriptures.in/scriptures/puranas-18-puranas-mahapurana/skanda-purana/vol-ii/chapter-64/topic-1).**

When 13th year of Pandavas Vanavasa was over, various kings gathered and were discussing stategies and prowess of each other. When there were discussing time limit of each king to kill enemies (within how much time a king alone can kill all enemies) Barbarika said he would kill everyone in a Muhurta. **[Chapter 66](http://www.hinduscriptures.in/scriptures/puranas-18-puranas-mahapurana/skanda-purana/vol-ii/chapter-66/topic-1)** describes it in detail.

> सूत उवाच
>
> इत्युक्तो वासुदेवेन सर्वभूतेश्वरेण च । 
>  सिंहवक्षाः पर्वताभो
> नानाभूषणभूषितः ॥ ६६-३५
>
> घटास्यो घटहासश्चऊर्ध्वकेशोऽतिदीप्तिमान् । 
> विद्युदक्षोवायुजवोयश्चेच्छेन्नाशयेज्जगत् ॥ ६६-३६
>
> देवीदत्तातुलबलो बर्बरीकोऽभ्यभाषत । 
>  यदि वो मानसं वीरा उपायस्य
> प्रदर्शने ॥ ६६-३७
>
> तदहं दर्शयाम्येष पश्यध्वं सहकेशवाः । 
>  इत्युक्त्वा धनुरारोप्य
> सन्दधे विशिखं त्वरन् । 
>  निःशल्यं चाऽपि सम्पूर्णं सिन्दूराभेण
> भस्मना ॥ ६६-३८
>
> आकर्णमाकृष्य च तं मुमोच 
>  मुखादथोद्भूतमभूच्च भस्म ॥ ६६-३९
>
> सेनाद्वये तच्च पपात शीघ्रं यस्यैव यत्राऽस्ति च मृत्युर्मम । ६६-४० (a)
>
> Sita said:
>
> 35-40a. On being asked thus by Vasudeva, the Lord of all living
> beings, Barbarika spoke out. He had the chest like a lion. He
> resembled a huge mountain. He was bedecked in different kinds of
> ornaments. His face resembled a pot. The sound of his laughter
> resembled the sound from a pot. The hair on his head stood up. He had
> great refulgence. His eyes shone like lightning streaks. He had the
> velocity of the wind. If he wished he could destroy the universe. He
> had unparalleled strength granted by the goddess. He spoke out thus,
> “O warriors, if you are inclined to see the means (to be) used, I
> shall exhibit it. All of you together with Kesava witness it.'
>
> After saying thus he strung his bow and hurriedly fitted the arrow
> thereto. The entire portion of the dart was filled with ash resembling
> saffron. The ash fell on the soldiers of both the armies exactly on
> the vulnerable spot. (If they were hit there they would die
> instantaneously.)
>
> सर्वरोमसु भीष्मस्य कण्ठे राधेयद्रोणयोः ॥ ६६-४० (b)
>
> ऊरौ दुर्योधनस्याऽपि शल्यस्याऽपिच वक्षसि । 
>  कण्ठे च शकुनेर्दीप्तं
> भगदत्तस्यचापतत् ॥ ६६-४१
>
> कृष्णस्य पादतलके कण्ठे द्रुपदमत्स्ययोः । 
>  शिखण्डिनस्तथा कट्यां
> कण्थे सेनापतेस्तथा ॥ ६६-४२
>
> पपात रक्तं तद्भस्म यत्र येषां च मर्मच । 
>  केवलं चैव पाण्डूनां
> कृपद्रौण्योश्च नास्पृशत् ॥ ६६-४३
>
> 40b-43. **The ash fell on the hair of Bhisma; on the neck of Karna and
> Drona; on the thigh of Duryodhana; on the chest of Salya; the
> brilliant ash fell on the necks of Sakuni and Bhagadatta; on the sole
> of the foot of Krsna; on the necks of Drupada and Matsya; on the hip
> of Sikhandin; on the neck of the commander-in-chief of the army
> (Dhrstadyumna). The red ash fell on the vulnerable spot of everyone.
> But the ash did not touch the Pandavas, Krpa and Asvatthama.**
>
> इति कृत्वा ततो भूयो बर्बरीकोऽभ्यभाषत । 
>  दृष्टं भवद्भिरेवं यन्मया
> मर्म निरीक्षितम् ॥ ६६-४४
>
> अधुना पातयिष्यामि मर्मस्वेषां शिताञ्छरान् । 
> देवीदत्तानमोघाख्यान्यैर्मरिष्यन्त्यमी क्षणात् ॥ ६६-४५
>
> शपथावः स्वधर्मस्यशस्त्रं ग्राह्यं न वः क्वचित् । 
> मुहूर्तात्पातयिष्यामि शत्रुनेताञ्छितैः शरैः ॥ ६६-४६
>
> 44-46. After doing thus, Barbarika spoke once again: “Was this noticed
> by you all how the vulnerable spot was located by me? Now I shall
> discharge sharp arrows on the vulnerable spots of these, **the arrows
> that will never fail, the arrows that the goddess granted me.**
> Thereby, they will die in a moment. There is a solemn oath on the
> Svadharma-your own Dharma. No weapon should be taken up by any of you.
> I shall make these enemies fall down (dead) within a short while by
> means of these sharp arrows.'

After uttering these words by Barbarika, Krishna immediately beheaded Barbarika. When everyone was awestruck, 14 Goddesses appeared and explained the reason for beheading.

Before incarnation of Krishna, all Devas went to abode of Lord Vishnu to save Earth from Rakshas. So, Lord Vishnu decided to incarnate as krishna. But a Yakhsa leader named **Suryavarchas** said he alone would kill all Rakshasas and there would be no need for Vishnu's incarnation. Brahma infuriated at his arrogance and cursed yaksha leader to get killed by Vishnu's incarnation Krishna.

> सूर्यवर्चेति यक्षेन्द्रश्चतुराशीतिकोटिपः । 
>  किमर्थं मानुषे लोके
> भवद्भिर्जन्म कार्यते ॥ ६६-५९
>
> मयि तिष्ठति दोषाणामनेकानां महास्पदे । 
>  सर्वे भवन्तो मोदन्तु
> स्वर्गेषु सहविष्णुना ॥ ६६-६०
>
> अहमेकोऽवतीर्यैतान् हनिष्यामि भुवोभरान् । 
>  स्वधर्मशपथा वो
> वैसन्तिचेज्जन्मप्राप्स्यथ ॥ ६६-६१
>
> In the meantime, a **Yaksa leader named Suryavarcas**, lord of
> eighty-four crores, lifted his hand and spoke loudly: “What for do you
> promise to take birth in the human world which is a receptacle of many
> defects (and that too) while I am alive? All of you may rejoice in the
> heavenly worlds along with Visnu, I alone shall incarnate and kill
> these people who become burden to the Earth. There is a solemn oath on
> your Dharma, if you take up birth.”
>
> इत्युक्तवचने ब्रह्मा क्रुद्धस्तं समभाषत । 
>  दुर्मते
> सर्वदेवानामविषह्यं महाभरम् ॥ ६६-६२
>
> स्वसाध्यं ब्रूषे मोहात्त्वं शापयोग्योऽसि बालिश । 
>  देशकालोचितं
> स्वीयं परस्य च बलं हृदा ॥ ६६-६३
>
> अविचार्यैव प्रभुषु वक्ति सोऽर्हति दण्डनम् । 
>  तस्माद् भूभारहरणे
> युद्धस्योपक्रमे सति ॥ ६६-६४
>
> शरीरनाशं कृष्णात्त्वमवाप्स्यसि न संशयः । 
>  एवं शप्तो ब्रह्मणाऽसौ
> विष्णुमेतदयाचत ॥ ६६-६५
>
> 62-65. When he spoke these words, the infuriated Brahma spoke to him:
> “O evil-minded one, you say that you can accomplish (the removal of)
> the great burden unbearable to all the Devas. It is only due to your
> delusion. O childish fellow, you are worthy of being cursed. Without
> pondering over what is relevant to the time and place, one's own power
> and that of the enemy, if anyone says anything in the midst of lords
> and masters, he deserves punishment. **Hence at the start of the
> battle for the purpose of removing the burden, you will undoubtedly
> meet with the destruction of your body at the hands of Krsna.**'

Suryavarchas requested Lord Vishnu to grant him the intellect to accomplish any task. Lord Vishnu granted that boon.

> 

> On being cursed thus by Brahma, he requested Visnu as follows:

> यद्येवं भविता नाशस्तदेकं देव प्रार्थये । 
>  जन्मप्रभृति मे देहि मतिं
> सर्वार्थसाधनीम् ॥ ६६-६६
>
> 66.“If my death must occur thus, O Lord, I make a single request. Grant me an intellect that accomplishes all tasks, ever since my
> birth.'

> ततस्तथेति तं प्राह केशवो देवसंसदि । 
>  शिरस्ते पूजयिष्यन्ति देव्याः
> पूज्यो भविष्यति ॥ ६६-६७

> 67.“So be it', said Kesava in the assembly of the Devas, “People will worship your head. You will be worthy of being adored by
> goddesses.'

Goddess sprayed amruta on Barbarika's head and Barbarika's head witnessed entire Kurukshetra War.

(Sanskrit verses are taken from [Dvaipayana.net](http://www.dvaipayana.net/purana/barbarika/barbarika-skandapurana.html) and English translation from Skanda Purana by Motilal Banarsidass Publishers).

Comment: thanks it is indeed a very good answer, I do not know why in televisions and in north india we all believed he is son of Arjun, Thanks for clearification

Comment: @RIshi There is a story in which son of Arjuna named "Iravan" is sacrificed before Mahabharata war. There is a [related question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/17390/what-do-scriptures-say-about-ir%c4%81v%c4%81n-son-of-arjuna-who-married-mohini-avatar) about this.  They confuse between Brabarika and Iravan.

Answer (score 0):

> In the Skanda Purana, Barbarika,Baliyadev (IAST Barbarīka) was the son of Ghatotkacha and Maurvi (Ahilawati), daughter of Muru, a Yadava king.[[Source]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barbarika)

The interesting thing about him is that:

> Before the Mahabharata war, Lord Krishna asked all the warriors how
>   many days they would take to end the war. All of them answered at an
>   average of 20-15 days. When asked, Barbarika answered that he will end
>   the war in just a minute.

Wait, how can he do that? Because he is the "bearer of three arrows" (you call it "self-propelled precision-guided munition system").

His **one** arrow is capable of marking all the things he wants to destroy.

His **second** arrow is capable of marking all the things he wants to save.

His **third** arrow destroys all the things marked by first arrow or unmarked by the second arrow.

Krishna tested and realized that no body would be able to escape his arrows.[[Source]](http://ritsin.com/tag/three-arrows/)

Barbarika wants to side with the weaker side, but Krishna asks him not to do so as that side will surely win.So, he keeps switching sides during the war.

So, is there something we can learn? Any metaphors may be? Sure.

> The three arrows are signs of three 'taapa's that a human being
>   experiences. These include the physical, the mental and the emotional
>   turmoils, conflicts and confusions that are found almost everywhere.
>   These three 'taapa's are cleared with chanting of name of Shri
>   Krishna. Thus, giving Barabarika the name "Shyaam", the Lord intended
>   to remove the three 'taapa's of human life, symbolized by the three
>   arrows, without which it might not be possible to destroy or overcome
>   the 'taapa's.
>
> One another legend says that the three arrows of Barabarika can be
>   used as follows: First arrow to mark all the near and dear ones,
>   relatives, etc., Second arrow to mark the people who are not part of
>   the war or who are not taking any side in the war, and the third arrow
>   to destroy everything that is not marked by first and second arrows.

Comment: Wikipedia is not the valid Source

Comment: I have always seen Arjun as his father since childhood in indian television..

Comment: You say wiki is not valid source, I agree, but wiki is based on references.https://books.google.com/books?id=6F0ZIBIL2ZAC&pg=PA155#v=onepage&q&f=false for example..