# Who was the wife of Ghatotkacha

Tags: ghatotkacha

Can anybody tell me that who was the wife of Ghatotkacha?

Comment: See [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/17803/3500).

Answer (score 3):

> Ahilawati (aka Maurvi) or Kamakatankata was the wife of Ghatotkacha?

According to Skanda Purana (Chapter 59) it explain fully

> http://www.dvaipayana.net/purana/barbarika/barbarika-skanda-summary.html

But We got different opinion when we look in to Google sources.

> Yudhishthira requested Krishna to suggest a suitable wife for ghatotkacha. Krishna  thought for a moment and said: **Kamakatankata, the daughter of the demon mura is suitable to be the wife of ghatotkacha.** After I killed the demon mura, she fought with me. When I invoked sudarshana chakra to kill her, Goddess Kamakhya appeared before me saying that she has granted invincibility to her along with a sword and shield. I agreed to stop fighting and requested the Goddess to make mura's daughter stop fighting as well. The Goddess embraced her devotee and asked her to stop fighting saying that even shiva cannot defeat Krishna. The Goddess also told her that she will become the daughter-in-law of bhIma. Hearing this, Mura's daughter bowed down and offered her obeisance to me. I told her: Stay in Pragjyotisha, ruled by naraka's son, bhagadatta. While residing at the city, you will marry the son of Bhima and Hidimbi. Mura's daughter made a condition that she will marry the man who conquers her by silencing her with questions as well as by subduing her in battle. Many demons went to win her in marriage but all of them were defeated by her.
>
> Hearing this Yudhishthira said: O lord! This girl does not appear to be suitable for Bhima's son. Suggest someone else. 
>   Bhima said: I approve what Krishna said. Let Hidimbi son bring mura's daughter. 
>   Arjuna said: Since Goddess Kamakhya has predicted that Ghatotkacha will marry mura's daughter, let him leave for pragjyotisha at once. 
>   Krishna said: No one equals ghatotkacha in prowess and intellect. Let him leave for prajyotisha without any delay. 
>   Ghatotkacha said: I am happy to obey your orders. He bowed down before Pandavas and Krishna.
>   Krishna said: Remember me at the time of debate. I will enhance your intellectual prowess. ghatotkacha rose up in the sky and departed for pragjyotisha.
>
> Ghatotkacha finally married Kamakatankata and they had a son named Barbarika.

Comment: From where did u copy this passage?

Comment: Different sources, all saying same story but I'm not sure from where I took this. I think it should be enough for answer and I guess it's a partial answer

Comment: Barbarika's story is said to be an interpolation, its only mentioned in Skanda Purana, not in the Mahabharata Itself.

Comment: You should mention the source as well.

Comment: I'm confused here.. I got one more source from Skanda purana, it's totally different http://www.dvaipayana.net/purana/barbarika/barbarika-skanda-summary.html