# What are the three Arrows of Barbarika and how he got them?

Tags: mahabharata, weapon, kshatriya

- It is said that Barbarika had Three Arrows which is the **Most powerful ones** and so he was sacrificed to Mahabharta War.

**QUESTION :**

- What are the Three Arrows of Barbarika and how he **Got them** ?
- Are these Three Arrows powerful than **Brahmashtra,Pasupathastra and Vaishnavaastra**.

Comment: Related and could be duplicate [Who was Barbarika?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/17764/3500)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Who was Barbarika?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/17764/who-was-barbarika)

Comment: @SreeCharan charan that question says only about  barbarika and about three arrows it has WIKIPEDIA AS ANSWER and a POST as SOURCE. they are not scriptural

Comment: One who voted to CLOSE please state the reason

Comment: @Sakthi See my answer for that question.

Comment: @TheDestroyer Friend i saw it but it has **Now I shall discharge sharp arrows on the vulnerable spots of these, the arrows that will never fail, the arrows that the goddess granted me**   this gives answer to **how he got them** but what are the three arrows and are they powerful than Brahmashtra,Pasupathastra and Vaishnavastra is not given

Comment: Possibly they are much more powerful than the weapons that u have mentioned. Otherwise why will he be stopped from participating in the war?