# The strongest warrior of all time in the time of Mahabharatha

Tags: mahabharata, war

I just watched this video today and got mesmerised: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q0Qw1HAVMtI&t=71s what sadhguru has stated.

A man from south India with just 3 arrows came to fight war, When krishna asks you have only 3, what can you do with it? He mentions, i can kill entire kauravas from 1 arrow and another arrow to kill entire pandavas. By the by who is this person and what is his name? Is that true story and was he a real character? What was his story?

Comment: The name is Barbarik if Im not wrong

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khatushyam

Comment: [awesome](https://sites.google.com/site/interestingstoriesofourepics/story-1)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Who was Barbarika?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/17764/who-was-barbarika) and [What are the three Arrows of Barbarika and how he got them?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/19536/5212)

Comment: Barbarika is the son of Ghatothkacha and grandson of Bheema. He desired to attain mukti in the quickest way possible. He learnt that getting killed by Vishnu is the quickest way to mukti. In order to make Krishna, an avatar of Vishnu, kill him, he obtains powerful arrows from Parvathi. When Mahabharatha war starts, he comes to finish off the war with just three arrows. Krishna understands this and tries to stop him. When Krishna fails in stopping him, he slays Barbarika. However, Krishna allows Barbarika to be alive till the war gets over.