# Name of the Demon who can finish the Mahabharatha in just a second?

Tags: mahabharata, krishna

What was the name of the demon who said to Lord Krishna that "I can finish the **Mahabharata war**  just in *second*, but I need your Permissions"? & then Lord Krishna didn't allow him to do so.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Who was Barbarika?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/17764/3500)

Comment: Are you talking about that Chinese Demon?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope this might be what you are looking for. It is from Wikipedia. Better citation from a specific edition of the MHB would be appreciated But I could not find it Without a few weeks of deeper research. Hope this is of help to steer you in the direction of your choice. Blessings.

[Barbarika (Belarsen) and his dialog with Krishna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barbarika#Barbarika_.28Belarsen.29_and_his_dialog_with_Krishna)

> Barbarika alias Khatushyamji Baliyadev alias Shyam was a grandson of
>   Bhima (second of the Pandava brothers), and the son of Ghatotkacha.
>   Ghatotkacha was the son of Bhima and Hidimbi. Even in his childhood,
>   Barbarika was a very brave warrior. He learnt the art of warfare from
>   his mother. The gods (ashtadeva) gave him the three infallible
>   arrows.[3] Hence, Barbarika came to be known as "Bearer of Three
>   Arrows". When Barbarika learnt that battle between the Pandavas and
>   the Kauravas had become inevitable, he wanted to witness what was to
>   be the Mahābhārata War. He promised his mother that if he felt the
>   urge to participate in the battle, he would join the side which would
>   be losing. He rode to the field on his Blue Horse equipped with his
>   three arrows and bow.
>
> Before the Mahabharata war began, Lord Krishna asked all the Pandavas
>   how many days they would take to finish Mahabharata war alone. Bhishma
>   answered that he would take 20 days to finish the war. Dronacharya
>   replied that it would take him 25 days. When Karna was asked, he said
>   he would take 24 days. Arjuna told Krishna it would take 28 days for
>   him to complete the battle by himself. In this manner, Lord Krishna
>   asked each warrior and received an answer.[citation needed]
>
> Krishna disguised as a Brahmin, stopped Barbarika to examine his
>   strength. When asked how many days he would take to finish the war
>   alone, Barbarika answered that he could finish it in one minute.
>   Krishna then asked Barbarika how he'd finish the great battle with
>   just three arrows. Barbarika replied that a single arrow was enough to
>   destroy all his opponents in the war, and it would then return to his
>   quiver. He stated that, the first arrow is used to mark all the things
>   that he wants to destroy. If he uses the second arrow, then the second
>   arrow will mark all the things that he wants to save. On using the
>   third arrow, it will destroy all the things that are not marked and
>   then return to his quiver. In other words, with one arrow he can fix
>   all his targets and with the other he can destroy them.