# Does anyone know which chapter (of Mahabharatha) the story of Barbarika is mentioned?

Tags: mahabharata, identification-request

This [Wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barbarika) gives extensive details of a character called Barbarika supposedly the son of Ghatotkacha and the Grandson of Bhima.

I am unable to find the chapter of Mahabharata where this character is mentioned. I even have a serious doubt whether this character actually exists at all or is this just a folklore).

Does someone know the chapter where he is mentioned?

Comment: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/23368/mentions-of-barbarik-or-yalambar-in-mahabharata check once

Comment: Thanks. I am also of the opinion that Barbarika is not mentioned in Mahabharata.